# Xamarin.Forms WebView - pass double click events to JavaScript

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a simple Xamarin.Forms application for iOS, with only a WebView that directs to a web app. In the web app itself, I have an event listener in order to handle double clicks on an element (by adding jQuery.on("click", Foo)  and check in there... Long story, that's not the issue).

When I click on the element, I indeed enter the callback ("Foo").
However, when I double click the element, nothing happenes. "Foo" is not executed even once, let alone twice.
If I change the event listener to "touchend" instead of "click", it works well, but that's not a feasible solution at the moment.

When I run the application in Safari mobile everything works well.

Any idea what may cause this issue?
How can I make the WebView to fire click events for every click?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your JS code. Moreover if you fired the "dblclick" since clicking the element twice? You can try to cancel it by `on("dblclick", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  //cancel system double-click event
    });`

Comment: My JS code is rather simple, something like: element.on("click", function(event) { /* do something */ });  The problem is that when I double click on the element, the callback function isn't executed even once. I also tried to add an event listener specific for double click and it didn't work.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your suggestion regarding the preventDefault - in my code, I need the "click" callback to be fired twice (for every click, as it indeed works in Safari), so I can't see how canceling the system double click helps, even if it works.